# Python lxml and xslt issue

Tags: python, django, xslt, lxml, centos7

I have some problem with lxml and python.

I have this code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
xml_dom = ET.parse(xml_path)
xslt_dom = ET.parse(xslt_path)

print('transforming...')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt_dom)
print('transformed: ', transform)
parsed_xml = transform(xml_dom)
print('all good!')
```

On my local environment, all works good (python 3.6.5 on a virtualenv with lxml 3.6.0).

The problem is, i have this code on a Centos 7 server, with the exact same specs (Python 3.6.5 and lxml 3.6.0), if i execute it from command line, all is good, when i put this code inside a Django (2.0) project, it "freeze" on this part:

```
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt_dom)
```

No exceptions, no errors, nothing. The print below that line never executes.
I changed permissions of the files, to apache group, set read permissions, and nothig works.

The weird thing is, from console works nice, from "apache + Django", don't.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.